# Patient Card Configuration Health Cloud

Tags: health-cloud

In our model, Patient data is stored in contact with a specific record type and all the patients are related to a single household account. We want to leverage patient card to display contact(patient) information however it is showing all contacts' information related to that Account instead of a single contact.

How can I show single contact data in Patient card?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not using the Health Cloud the way it was intended, so some side effects are to be expected. An Individual is an Account and a Contact, and a Patient is an Account, Contact, and has a Care Plan. Each Patient should have their own unique care plan, thus each patient should be their own account.

It doesn't matter if you don't "use" accounts in the traditional sense, you must organize your data this way if you expect the system to behave correctly. You should read more in the [Health Cloud Implementation Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.health_cloud.meta/health_cloud/). In particular, please read the sections in [The Big Picture for Setting Up Health Cloud](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.health_cloud.meta/health_cloud/admin_planning.htm) and [Get to Know the Health Cloud Data Model](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.health_cloud.meta/health_cloud/admin_data_model.htm).

This will be doubly important should you decide to allow your patients to have access to Communities, since all Contacts belonging to the same Account will be able to share information, and I'm pretty sure you don't want all of your clients to see each others' case plans.

Comment: The issue with single Account is, we are not able to add guarantor and emergency contact for the individual patient account. We want to show guarantor and emergency contact for the patient in the patient card. With existing cloud model, how can we associate multiple contacts to a patient account.